# How to push/pull with Gitkrakent to/from Heroku?

Tags: heroku, gitkraken

When I try to push/pull with Gitkrakent to/from Heroku, GitKraken tells me :

["Please log in to continue"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Por1h.png)

What is the requested "user/login" ?
(The one from my personal Heroku account doesn't work").
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 23):

Your username is the email you used to login on heroku.

The password is your auth token. You can get this by running these in console:

`heroku login` To login

`heroku auth:token` To get your password for GitKraken

Comment: I had to use `heroku auth:login`

Comment: to make your answer better i would write it like this :
To login : `heroku login`
To get your password for GitKraken : `heroku auth:token`

because people can think pipe `|` is required but it is only explaining command result

Comment: The token can also be retrieved from the Heroku UI: Account Settings > Account Tab > Scroll down to Api Key and copy the key.

Answer (score 3):

To use Heroku git (something like https://git.heroku.com/reponame.git) with GitKraken, please use **email as username**, and use **authorization token as password**.

I create a long-term password to use with GitKraken by

1. Go to Heroku UI then login
2. Account Settings
3. Applications
4. Authorization / Create
   authorization *(don't set expire if you want long-term access)*

Answer (score 2):

Pointing remote to ssh protocol solved this for me.

`https://git.heroku.com/{your-app}.git` => `git@heroku.com:{your-app}.git`

Make sure you have same updated ssh keys in your account settings in Heroku related to that repository.

You may use ssh-agent to handle many keys